# How to do Convert Latitude/Longitude To Address

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I wrote some code this codes worked but only get latitude and longitude 
but ı want  convert latitude and longitude from Street adress.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>location</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      document.write("latitude= " + position.coords.latitude);
      document.write("longitude= " + position.coords.longitude);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Street address where? US? Europe?

Comment: did you use Google map?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: ı cant use google apis  Could you suggest a video this apis ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get latitude and longitude from an address, then the process is called geocoding and can be completed using the Google Maps API. Here is sample python code to run this conversion:

```
import requests
import json

def convert(address):
    URL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address + '&key=[INSERT API KEY]&callback=initMap'
    r = requests.get(URL).json()
    return r['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
```

If instead you would like to get the address based on the latitude and longitude, reverse geocoding, also from the Google Maps API, is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Google Reverse Geocoding:

[Reverse geocoding Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)